# How to copy nested SQL tables (implementing a change history)

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, copying

I'm a software development apprentice currently trying to implement a simple checklist with the added trouble of keeping track of every version/every change of said checklist. This means that whenever a new category is added or the name of it is changed (same for questions), a new row in the "ChecklistVersion" table is created and all categories and questions of the most recent ChecklistVersion is copied to the new one. This is needed to preserve the entire history of changes. See the following [database scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLP2m.png).

Another quirk from this database is, that it's used and created by a CMS (Intrexx) which doesn't use auto-increment for primary keys.

For further clarification, this scheme is used to represent the following:

- Checklist A

  - Version 1

    - Category 1

      - Question 1
      - ...
      - Question n
    - Category 2

      - Question 3
  - Version 2

    - Category 1

      - Question 1
- Checklist B

  - Version 1
  - ...

Thus far the copying process works for categories, but I'm stuck at copying the questions. These are my queries:

First, create a new ChecklistVersion entry and return its ID:

```sql
insert into ChecklistVersion
(
    ID,
    ChecklistID
)
values
(
    (
        select coalesce(max(ID)+1, 1) /* Get next ID */
        from ChecklistVersion
    ),
    ? /* This value gets replaced by the checklist ID in Java code */
)
returning ID;
```

The next step is copying the categories:

```sql
insert into Category
(
    ID,
    ChecklistVersionID,
    Name
)
select
       (select max(ID)+1 from Category) - 1 + ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID), /* See (1) below */
       ?, /* This gets replaced by the ChecklistVersion ID returned by the previous query */
       Name
from Category
where ChecklistVersionID = ?; /* Gets replaced in code by the most recent ChecklistVersion ID
                                 which serves as the source for the categories to be copied */
```

(1): The line generates the next highest ID for the category, it's ugly but I don't know of a better way. The subselect is only executed once, therefore the ROW_NUMBER() is needed to increment further.

Now imagine the following table entries:

```
           Category                              Question

| ID | ChecklistVersionID | Name |    | ID | CategoryID | Text      |
|----|--------------------|------|    |----|------------|-----------|
| 1  | 1                  | Cat1 |    | 1  | 2          | Question1 |
| 2  | 1                  | Cat2 |    | 2  | 1          | Question2 |
                                      | 3  | 2          | Question3 |
```

After successfully copying the ChecklistVersion with ID 1 the following result is expected:

```
           Category                              Question

| ID | ChecklistVersionID | Name |    | ID | CategoryID | Text      |
|----|--------------------|------|    |----|------------|-----------|
| 1  | 1                  | Cat1 |    | 1  | 2          | Question1 |
| 2  | 1                  | Cat2 |    | 2  | 1          | Question2 |
| 3  | 2                  | Cat1 |    | 3  | 2          | Question3 |
| 4  | 2                  | Cat2 |    | 4  | 4          | Question1 |
                                      | 5  | 3          | Question2 |
                                      | 6  | 4          | Question3 |
```

So not only does each question need to be copied, it also needs to have the corresponding *new* CategoryID assigned. So somehow I need to get the mapping between the previous and new IDs of the categories (1 -> 3 and 2 -> 4 in this example).

I hope my question is clear, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the solution using a temporary table to use the mapping from the selection statement in the insertion of the categories as well as the questions, here's my solution:

```
/* Create temporary table with the categories that will be copied,
   provides the mapping between the old and new category IDs (CopyID and ID).
   This is pretty much equivalent to the select statement in the original insertion
   query. */
create temp table CategoriesToCopy as
select (select max(ID)+1 from Category) - 1 + ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) as CopyID,
       ? as ChecklistVersionID,
       Name,
       ID
from Category
where ChecklistVersionID = ?;

/* Insert categories just like before, but using the temporary
   table instead */
insert into Category
(
    ID,
    ChecklistVersionID,
    Name
)
select CopyID, ChecklistVersionID, Name
from CategoriesToCopy;

/* Insert questions using mapping of temporary table */
insert into Question
(
    ID,
    CategoryID,
    QuestionText
)
select
    (select max(ID)+1 from Question) - 1 + ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Question.ID),
    CategoriesToCopy.CopyID, /* use new category ID for copied question */
    Question.QuestionText
from Question
inner join CategoriesToCopy /* join rows which correspond to the old category IDs */
    on CategoriesToCopy.ID = Question.CategoryID;

/* Delete temporary table */
drop table CategoriesToCopy;
```